# Problem installing openssl 2.2.1 gem in MacOS

Tags: ruby, openssl, rbenv

I am working in a project where the openssl (2.2.1) gem is used and ruby 2.7.5 is used. I successfully installed Ruby 2.7.5 with rbenv (ruby-build helped install it by downloading openssl 1.1.1).

However, when I do `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
extconf.rb:113:in `<main>': OpenSSL >= 1.0.1, < 3.0.0 or LibreSSL >= 2.5.0 is required (RuntimeError)
...
An error occurred while installing openssl (2.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install openssl -v '2.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling
```

I tried installing the gem manually by doing this: `gem install openssl -v '2.2.1' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)` but this didn't work. I don't know what else to do. The command `brew --prefix openssl@1.1` returns `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1` but looks like it is using the other openssl version I have installed which is the one I get if I do `openssl version` (this returns `OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023)`).

I tried installing the gem with `gem install openssl -v '2.2.1' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)` and expected that the gem will be installed with the openssl dir specified

Answer (score 0):

For install gem openssl v2, install openssl@1.1 first.

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Set ENV `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig`, then execute `gem install openssl -v 2.1.2 -- --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"`.

Or simply execute command: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig gem install openssl -v 2.1.2 -- --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"`.

**Please replace openssl version 2.1.2 to your version.**